# Аналог std :: endl и std::flush в go

Tags: golang, стандартный-ввод-вывод

В заголовке всё сказано. Мы все знаем,что в большинстве пользовательских современных ОС стандартный ввод и вывод работает через буфер. Чтобы буфер скинуть в c++ есть `std::flush` и `std::endl`,который ещё и переносит на новую строку.
Есть ли такое в Go?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Короткий ответ**

Нет

**Более развёрнутый**

Практически все операции вывода в Go используют интерфейсы [`io.Writer`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Writer) или [`io.WriteCloser`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#WriteCloser). В этих интерфейсах есть только метод `Write`. Эти интерфейсы радикально проще стандартного `std::basic_stream`. Метод `Flush` или аналоги в `io.Writer` отсутствуют.

Теперь об объектах `std::cin` и `std::cout`. В Go им соответствуют `os.Stdin` и `os.Stdout`. Переменная `os.Stdout` - это указатель на объект типа [`os.File`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#File).

В Go вывод в файлы не буферизуется, метод `File.Write` пишет напрямую в файловый дескриптор через системный вызов [`pwrite`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/pwrite). Соответственно, в типе `File` нет метода, аналогичного `std::Flush`. Есть метод [`Sync`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#File.Sync), который вызывает системный вызов [`fsync`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fsync.html) для открытого файлового дескриптора, но это не то. Этот системный вызов заставляет ядро сбросить на диск буферы, отведённые под файловый дескриптор.

Из-за того, что `File` пишет напрямую в файл, функции `fmt.Print` и `fmt.Println`, а так же методы `File.WriteString` и `File.Write`, очень медленные. На больших объемах вывода они медленнее буферизованного вывода раз в 100.

Буферизованный ввод-вывод предоставляет пакет `bufio`. В пакете определён тип [`bufio.Writer`](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#Writer), в котором есть метод [`Flush`](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#Writer.Flush). Этот тип рад в *дцать* ускоряет вывод, но, к сожалению, нет типа для буферизованного файла: нельзя написать `os.Stdout = bufio.NewWriter(os.Stdout)`. Поэтому если вам нужен быстрый аналог `fmt.Print`, то нужно пользоваться `fmt.Fprint` и явно указывать writer:

```
Stdout_Buffered := bufio.NewWriter(os.Stdout)
...
fmt.Fprintln(Stdout_Buffered, "Hello, world!")
...
Stdout_Buffered.Flush()
```

Аналога для `std::endl` в стандартных пакетах Go нет. Функция [`fmt.Fprintln`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Fprintln) пишет в объект `io.Writer` системно-зависимый конец строки, но, поскольку `io.Writer` не содержит никаких аналогов flush, нижележащий буфер (если есть) эта функция не синхронизует.